# How can I change the default separator of group_concat() using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to `group_concat` using SQLAlchemy. The problem is I want to change the separator from `,` to `:`

```
### code #####
.......
db.session.query(c1.ID,c1.cap ,func.group_concat(c1.Name.distinct(), ':' )).join(c2,(chart1.ID == c2.ID)).filter(c1.cap ==82).group_by(c1.ID).all()
```

It gives the below output:

```
[('ECE358', 82, 'CNT:,DB:')]
```

But I want the below:

```
[('ECE358', 82, 'CNT:DB')]
```

Comment: You could try `group_concat(c1.Name.distinct() separator ':')`, to see if that would work.

Comment: it shows invalid syntax. Can I import separator? if yes then how?

Comment: The quick'n'dirty solution using `op('SEPARATOR')` can be found at the bottom of the linked Q/A.